JSON data (mostly numbers), 1000+ characters long, making the QR code too crowded for scanners to recognize. Any ideas to solve it?
Here is my thing: so I need to generate a QR code for my data. My data is in JSON format, primarily numbers. I also use react typescript and nextjs on the front end. But my proof is super long, which is 1000+ characters long， so it is hard for the scanner to recognize as the QR is crowded. Any suggestions?
I tried basic pako library to compress the data down to 780 characters but still not working. Tried enlarging the qr code size but not working.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
